# When making HTTP raw POST request multipart/form-data with cURL PHP, how to properly set the Content-Length header?

Tags: php, curl, multipartform-data, content-length

I have just a question about the way I need to set the Content-Length header using curl in PHP to make multipart/form-data POST HTTP requests.

For example, I have a PHP script which makes a curl POST uploading an image to the server, the content of the HTTP entity body of the request would look like this:

```
------Boundary123
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="image.png"
Content-Type: image/png

... contents of image.png
------Boundary123--
```

I do something like this:

```
 $bodiEntity = "--".$boundary."\r\n".
               'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="'.$fileName.'"'."\r\n".
               'Content-Type: img/png'."\r\n\r\n".
                file_get_contents($fileName)."\r\n". // binary contents of file
                "--".$boundary."--\r\n";
```

But then, which value should I set for the Content-Length header? I know, it is the number of bytes of the  entity body, but how should I handle the "\r\n"?
I mean, if I do `strlen("\r\n")` I get 2 as return value, but I guess it should be 1 (meaning) one byte when dealing with sending multipart/form-data, am I right?

So should I just use `strlen()` for the strings like boundary string, Content-Disposition, Content-Type and count "\r\n" as a single char and use `filesize()` to get the filesize of the file in bytes and then sum all the values to get the final value for the Content-Length header? Or should I just count "\r\n" as 2 char as PHP does?

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: Doesn't `cURL` do it automatically for you?

Comment: I don't know, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Count "\r\n" as two bytes. The CRLF pair is two bytes long. The entire body including

```
 - the boundary prefix ("--"), 
 - boundary, 
 - the content bytes, 
 - the interim boundaries and their prefixes, 
 - the final boundary prefix, 
 - boundary and boundary post fix,
```

all should be accounted for in the content-length.

As for the content-length. There is no content-length defined for each file part in a multi-part request as of HTTP 1.1.

However, gross Content-length header should be defined in the beginning of the request.
You may wish to read the [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230.txt) Section 3.3.2. It has been written by one of the principle web and HTTP standards author [Roy Thomas Fielding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roy_Fielding).

But there are numerous other ways in which a file can be sent as a request, it doesn't necessarily need to be bounded in a boundary based multipart request. The other mechanism in POST method itself is raw content type request. The content is transmitted just after the headers end in the request, followed by an empty line (read "\r\n").

Other mechanisms include PUT requests which can also work in the similar fashion. Both of these have differences that separate them wide apart, technically, although I don't think going into that detail has any concern with the question, so I'll just skip it.